# JDBC connection to Kerberos enabled Apache phoenix

Tags: jdbc, kerberos, apache-phoenix

We have a phoenix service which is Kerberos enabled. We also have a Data virtualization server (based on Tomcat) which is also kerberos enabled (Denodo server). We would like to have Denodo connect to Phoenix so Denodo users can get data from Phoenix. We are confused as far as the syntax we need to use. From JDBC personal clients (DBeaver and Squirrel) we can use this syntax and it connects correctly:

jdbc:phoenix:myserver.mycompany.com:2181:/hbase-secure:user.name@MYCOMPANY.COM:/Users/user.name/krb5cc_user.name

Now, when we try to connect from the Denodo server we cannot use a personal keytab. So we are trying with this format:

jdbc:phoenix:myserver.mycompany.com:2181:/hbase-secure:HTTP/myserver.mycompany.com@MYCOMPANY.COM:/etc/security/keytabs/myservice.keytab

That did not work and we get this error:

ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
  Login failure for HTTP/myserver.mycompany.com@MYCOMPANY.COM from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/myservice.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

After doing a lot of googling, we have tried different iterations of that principal to

hbase/hdpopst@MYCOMPANY.COM

and always end up with the same error. So, I have two questions: is there an official documentation from Phoenix on this subject? we have not found it. Is that the correct syntax to connect these two services via JDBC?

Comment: To begin with, did you test the principal/keytab combination in the context of the Denodo service, i.e. `sudo -u whatever_linux_user_runs_Denodo_service kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/myservice.keytab HTTP/myserver.mycompany.com@MYCOMPANY.COM`

Comment: If `kinit` works (with the OS Kerberos library), enable the Java Kerberos library debug flags in Denodo with `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` _(then find out where Denodo stores its console StdOut / StdErr streams... and get ready for a weird experience)_